# Как подружить django с mqtt по ASGI

Tags: django, django-channels, channels

Мне нужен способ интеграции django с mqtt с помощью библиотеки channels[daphne] (https://channels.readthedocs.io/) . Цель асинхронный сбор данных от сетевого сервера LoRaWAN (https://www.chirpstack.io/).